# Хостинг Flask с помощью DriveToWeb

Tags: python, flask, хостинг

Могу ли я опубликовать приложение на Flask с базами данных с помощью [DriveToWeb](https://www.drv.tw/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Боюсь, что нет, так как DriveToWeb даёт доступ только к статическим HTML+CSS страницам. Вы можете использовать pythonanywhere.com. [По ссылке](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/121/) туториал с тем, как развернуть сайт на Flask с базой данных

Comment: А есть  ещё бесплатная альтернатива этому сервису.Просто здесь прибавка pythonanywhere выдаёт то что сайт на python.

Comment: @AhmedAbishev не совсем понял ваш комментарий. Хостить сайт на flask с базового данных на Pythonanywhere можно и с бесплатным тарифом, в ответе я приложил ссылку на инструкцию

Comment: Я знаю что это бесплатно,но прибавка pythonanywhere к домену выдаёт то что сайт написан на python и в целях безопасности я хочу чтобы вы мне предложили альтернативу pythonanywhere которая также как и pythonanywhere  будет бесплатной

Comment: @AhmedAbishev он так называется лишь потому что позволяет хостить проекты на Python, не более. Тем более, у pythonanywhere множество положительных отзывов

Comment: Ок вы не поняли что я хотел сказать просто предложите альтернативу

Comment: @AhmedAbishev вы можете использовать vercel, или qovery, но я не могу точно сказать, каким образом можно разместить сайт на flask с базой данных на этих сервисах. Вы также можете использовать платные VPS или VDS, это наиболее надёжный вариант